# Bicon. Incorrect exit from shell, open in ranger

Tags: terminal, bashrc, ranger

Installed bicon-git, this is written in .bashrc

```
# hack to launch bicon if not launched
if ! [[ "$(ps -p $(ps -p $(echo $$) -o ppid=) -o comm=)" =~ 'bicon'* ]]; then
  bicon.bin
fi
```

Launch ranger

```
[~] -> ranger
```

make

```
Shift + s
```

problem

```
[dir] -> exit
exit
done
    [dir] -> exit
[~] ->
```

How to fix double input?

p.s. Arch, sakura, st

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `bicon.bin` try `exec bicon.bin`, possibly with arguments to run your shell as a login shell.

When you run `bicon.bin` it spawns a shell, so now you have (1) the original shell, (2) `bicon.bin` running, and (3) the shell spawned by `bicon.bin`. With `exec` the original shell is replaced by `bicon.bin`.

Answer (score 1):

first thing to understand that bicon is virtual shell, so you need to exit twice one from bicon and one from bash.

So to avoid double .bashrc command doings, you must put command that including bicon in top of .bashrc.

Also to avoid double exit, you can do:

```
alias exit='kill -9 $(ps -p $PPID -o ppid=)'
```